# Получить id дочернего элемента и использовать его в href родителя

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть следующий код:

```
    <ul class="parent-list-menu">
    <li><a href="">Элемент первого уровня</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Элемент первого уровня</a></li>
        <ul class="child-list-menu collapse">
            <li><a href="">Элемент второго уровня</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Элемент второго уровня</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Элемент первого уровня</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Элемент первого уровня</a></li>
        <ul class="child-list-menu collapse">
            <li><a href="">Элемент второго уровня</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Элемент второго уровня</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Это список пунктов меню, некоторые из которых имеют свои сложенные списки.

Задача состоит в следующем: если у пункта меню первого уровня есть вложенный список, то добавить перед них html-код, по клику на который вложенное меню второго уровня будет разворачиваться collapse-ом (верстка на bootstrap 3).
что делаю я:

```
$('.child-list-menu.collapse').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'list' + i); //добавляю уникальный id каждому вложенному списку, т.к. это id должен быть в ссылке на разворачивающий список
});

$('ul.parent-list-menu li ul').parent().children('a').prepend('<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">'); //добавляю непосредственно ссылку на разворот списка

var link = $('.child-list-menu.collapse').attr('id'); //получаю id вложенного списка

$("ul.parent-list-menu li a").attr("href", "#"+link); // подставляю полученный id  в ссылку, раскрывающую блок-вложенный список
```

то есть я пытаюсь в каждом li, имеющем дочерний ul, получить id этого вложенного ul и подставить его в href ранее добавленной ссылки. Частично получается, но подставляется только id первого списка, понимаю, что где-то ошибаюсь, но не понимаю где.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, ошибка в разметке. У вас вложенные ul не являются дочерними элементами li, а находятся между ними.

Во-вторых, js-код, можно сократить до

```
$('li > ul').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'list' + i);
    $(this).prepend('<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#'+ i +'" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">+</a>');
});
```

Если я правильно понял задачу.

Comment: спасибо, работает отлично